# Windowing function: Finding max value from LAG()

Tags: sql-server, max, windowing

I'm currently working my way through the exam study book, *Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012*. I've been learning SQL over the last few months and I am currently looking over windowing functions. I came to this application question and it got me thinking about another question, which I'll list below:

[image]

So in the columns diffprev and diffnext it only lists the difference between the previous and the next value. How could I list the maximum difference between subsequent values across all of the rows (partitioned by custid)? So just scanning the table, I see that in custid 1's history, the greatest difference between subsequent rows is $548. Then for custid 2, the greatest difference is $390.95. I could see these values appearing in a maxdiff column across all the rows pertaining to the partition.

Thank you for aiding my studying!

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's probably best you try it yourself first instead of somebody giving you an answer.

Comment: @FutbolFan I've tried wrapping the query listed above in MAX(), but that didn't work.

Comment: If you could create a sqlfiddle example, I can help you out. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7

Comment: @FutbolFan I thought this would be a rather simple problem that someone could quickly help me with. It appears this is something better asked to a colleague.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for the value, this should work:

```
with cte as (
   select custid, val - lag(val) 
      over (partition by custid order by orderdate, orderid) as prevVal
   from Sales.OrderValues
)
select custid, max(abs(val))
from cte
group by custid
```

If you want the details of the rows that attain that maximum, it'll be a bit more work.

Bonus tip - pictures of text are the worst. You're more likely to get help if the people helping don't need to type your code out. Even better though would be a fully functioning example (complete with table definitions and sample data) so we can verify against your data!